# Proving $|\inf f(x) -\inf g(x)| \le \inf| f(x) -g(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Let $f$ and $g$ be bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$, let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A \subset B$, prove that $\left|\inf\limits_A f(x) -\inf\limits_B g(x)\right| \le$ $\inf\limits_B \left| f(x) - g(x) \right|$.

I could prove this for the supremum, as $\sup_A f\le \sup_B(f-g)+\sup_A g \le sup_B|f-g| +\sup_B g$.

Comment: If $f(x)=1+x$ and $g(x)=2x$ on $A=B=[0,1]$ then $\inf f = 1$, $\inf g=0$, so LHS is $1$. But $f(1)=g(1)$ so RHS is $0$

Comment: Thanks, could you take a look at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S240589632030834X
I don't understand how they write equation (31) (you need the definition after equation 11).

Comment: I think the correct statement would be $| \inf f -\inf g| \le \sup | f -g|$.